# Column bind in R for list

Tags: r, list

I create a list of matrix:

```
   mylist1<-lapply(1:10, function(x) matrix(NA, nrow=2, ncol=2))
   mylist2<-lapply(1:10, function(x) matrix(NA, nrow=2, ncol=2))
```

i want to append per column another list of the same type.

I tried with:

`final=mapply(c, mylist1, mylist2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)`

i want to access to "final" with matrix notation so with final[i][j],where each element of final is a matrix

Comment: Use `cbind` instead of `c`

Comment: @akrun Looks answerworthy, along with mentioning that extraction will be via `[i,j]` not `[i][j]`, I mean `cbind(mylist1,mylist2)[2,2]`

Comment: @Frank I think there may be dupes for this

Comment: It doesn't work,i tried final=mapply(cbind, mylist1, mylist2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)